# Homestead not mapping files

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I'm new to Laravel and I'm trying to get Laravel homestead to work, but no matter what I do the files on the VM will not map to my hard drive. I've tried on Windows and Mac thinking it might have been a windows problem, but it won't work on my Mac either. Also, when I try halting the machine and re provisioning, it deletes the contents of the project on the VM, I have no idea why this happens

Here is my homestead.yaml file (mac), on Windows it would be the same but with C://pathtofolder instead of the ~

Thanks in advance

```
    ---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/code/test
      to: /home/vagrant/test    
sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/test/public

databases:
    - homestead

features:
    - mariadb: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Edit - the issue is that I was making the project in the vagrant SSH, not on my disk. It maps from the disk to the VM, not the other way around, it seems.

Comment: Try using absolute paths instead of `~`.

Comment: Did you ssh into the VM to check the content of the folder `/home/vagrant/test`?

Comment: @ljubadr yes, I do this each time I provision before and after. Before, everything is there like normal, then after I provision everything disappears

Comment: What do you mean by: "It deletes the contents of my project on the VM", when you also state that there's no mapping happening?

Comment: @wschopohl before I reload the VM and provision all the laravel project contents are present (public, app etc), after I reload and provision it becomes empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you stated you did, are you sure you executed these commands:

```
vagrant halt
vagrant provision
vagrant up
```

As far as mapping goes I would do this:

```
folders:
    - map: ~/code
      to: /home/vagrant/code    
sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/test/public
```

And start a new project by this:

```
cd /home/vagrant
laravel new test
```

Comment: Every time I make a new project I always restart the  VM and provision it. Usually I do vagrant reload --provision, I tried vagrant halt, vagrant up, vagrant provision and  the same thing happened. When I ssh in and run ls or dir -l it returns empty. I checked before I provisioned, and the normal files were all present; they were deleted after I provisioned

Comment: Also, I am creating the laravel project by doing vagrant ssh, then cd /home/vagrant then doing laravel new project, is this correct?? 

I also tried doing mkdir in /home/vagrant and then setting the cd to that directory and making the project there, again no success.

Comment: I think there's your error. Try to make a laravel project inside the test folder or map the code folder

Comment: I think it's important that you map an existing folder on your host to vagrant and then work inside that..

Comment: theres my issue!! I had it backwards, ive been trying to fix this for days.... facepalm
Im new to laravel / homestead and using the command line in general if you cant tell
Thanks!

Comment: never had this error, but it makes sense now. Your test folder was empty on the host, you filled it in the vm and when you provision it seems to copy the (empty) host folder of the vm folder. Only after that the syncing happens in the other direction, too.. Well, glad you solved it!

Comment: @wschopohl - I've been chasing this issue for weeks, trying to set up a new Linux dev laptop, coming from years of Laravel dev in Windows/Laragon. With your steps above, are you starting from the host home folder, or the folder containing the Homestead.yaml & Vagrantfile? I think I'm getting messed up with the relative paths to I'm not sure which base.

Comment: If your problem is similar to the above, the solution is to first map a folder on your host system to the vagrant guest system. 1st line above is on you host, second line is path on your guest machine. vagrant ssh into the machine and habe a look at the mapped folder. You should see it and it should contain the files of your host folder, if there are any in there. Then create a new laravel project from the guest system in that folder. The newly created files should also show up in your host folder.. Hope you could follow..